# Shell Script and yum, what to do when package is not available. Centos

Tags: shell, scripting, centos, yum

I’d like to install a series of packages using script shell.

**Question is** : what to do when package is not available?
Script idea is:
if the package is installed go to the next one
if the package is available to be installed, install it,
if the package is not available exit the script, or to alert me about that package. Press a key to continue or so.
Thanks!

**More Info:**
While ago Monk posted this sentence

***yum list installed vnc-server >/dev/null && echo "vnc-server installed." || yum -y install vnc-server***

** it will return vnc-server installed or it will install it.**

I tried to install mariadb but – mariadb is not available in Centos 6.6 I should install other repository or something I don’t know yet, **the point is script’s behavior.**

***pkg=mariadb || yum list installed $pkg >/dev/null && echo "--> $pkg installed." || yum install $pkg***

this line as it is will return - - > mariadb installed.

( this return is wrong because MariaDB is not available)

In the command line typing

***yum install mariadb***

it will return

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror

Setting up Install Process

Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile

base: mirrors.tripadvisor.com

extras: mirrors.seas.harvard.edu

updates: mirrors.lga7.us.voxel.net

**No package mariadb available.**

Error: Nothing to do

*Thanks!*

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to check yum's exit code (untested Bash code):

```
yum list $pkg > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "Installing $pkg"
    yum -y install $pkg
else
    echo "$pkg not found or unknown error."
fi
```

Comment: Thanks! that script detect that a package ( mariadb is not listed ) that's good.

In my case vnc-server is part of the repository, it can be install the script give me this Error:

No matching Packages to list vnc-server not found or unknown error.